# Font quality in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, fonts, rendering, interpolation

I use fonts instead of Icons in my UI, suppose that I design a check mark in a font creator application, export ttf, embed the font in my project as a resource and then use it like this:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Content>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="C" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontFamily="./#MyFont"/>
                <TextBlock Text="OK" FontFamily="verdana"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

The problem is when I use my font in various sizes, the quality of characters is very bad.

I tryed UseLayoutRounding, RenderOptions, TextOptions, SnapsToDevicePixels and yet not a satisfactory result.

To show you how the poor quality is, I used an LCD font called Famirids and take snapshots of some various sizes. Look at the code and the snappshots:

```
<DockPanel Margin="10">
    <Slider x:Name="slider1" Minimum="1" Maximum="50" Value="17" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <Label Content="Why this is like this?" FontFamily="./#Famirids" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Viewbox Height="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label Content="Why this is like this?" FontFamily="./#Famirids" FontSize="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </UniformGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

[<<< **This is the snapshots** >>>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OeZw.png)

As you can see, even the Viewbox does not solve the problem. So please help me what to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found any answer for my question yet. Isn't there any solution really?

Comment: Hello everybody? Any comment? Any suggestion?